# how to create pickerview in storyboard as popover with done button on uitoolbar

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios6, uipopovercontroller

I have created the above example using code but was wondering if same can be achieved using storyboard.

I am a noob in ios and would like to know how to go about it.
 Thanks in Advance.

Code without storyboard and done button:

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController

UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
[datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];
[datePicker setTag:10];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Result) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

popoverContent.view = popoverView;
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
popoverController.delegate=self;
[popoverContent release];

[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:tempButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];//tempButton.frame where you need you can put that frame
```